# A + B without arithmetic operators, Python vs C++

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was trying to solve an old question:

> Write a function that add two [integer] numbers A and B. You should not use + or any arithmetic operators.

The best solution is like this, quoted from "[LintCode-A+B Problem](http://www.cnblogs.com/lishiblog/p/4194937.html)":

> For a + b in any base, we can treat the plus as two part: 1. a + b without carry; 2. the carry generated by a +b. The a+b then equals to part 1 plus part 2. If part1+part2 generates more carry, we can then repeat this procedure, until there is no carry.

I can understand this algorithm and everything seems good, so I tested it on [lintcode](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/a-b-problem/) with code pasted below.

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param a: The first integer
    @param b: The second integer
    @return:  The sum of a and b
    """
    def aplusb(self, a, b):

        while b != 0:
            carry = a & b
            a = a ^ b
            b = carry << 1

        return a
```

But surprisingly, it gave me `Time Limit Exceeded` error in test case `[100, -100]`. So I ran it locally and print a, b for every loop:

```
(-8, 8)
(-16, 16)
(-32, 32)
(-64, 64)
(-128, 128)
(-256, 256)
(-512, 512)
(-1024, 1024)
(-2048, 2048)
(-4096, 4096)
(-8192, 8192)
(-16384, 16384)
(-32768, 32768)
(-65536, 65536)
(-131072, 131072)
...
```

The calculation is correct, so I think this algorithm does not work for such input but when I wrote the same algorithm in C++, it just works:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int aplusb(int a, int b) {
        while (b!=0){
            int carry = a & b;
            a = a^b; 
            b = carry << 1;
        }
        return a;
    }
};
```

I don't know what should be asked exactly, basically the questions are:

1. Why does C++ give the correct output `0` while Python doesn't?
2. If I use Python, how do I modify this algorithm to make it work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The binary, 2's complement representation of `-4` is

```
...11100
```

Yes, I really do mean infinitely many `1`'s to the left; this is a binary repeating numeral. Technically, `4` is a repeating numeral too:

```
...00100
```

it's just repeating `0`'s to the left.

Your addition problem is

```
   ...11100
+  ...00100
--------------------
   ...00000
```

The operators `^`, `<<`, and `&` have no trouble computing with infinitely many binary digits, but the problem is that there are infinitely many carries, and you are computing them *one digit at a time*. This will never finish.

Thus, you have to recognize when this algorithm will get stuck in this situation and do something else to account for it.

---

You don't run into this problem in C/C++, because, for example, if `int` is 32-bits, then all of the digits except for the rightmost 31 digits get collapsed into a single bit, so it does the remaining carries all at once.

However, technically speaking, the meaning of left shifting an `int` is in terms of the value as an integer, rather than as a bit pattern, so you are invoking *undefined behavior* if the two most significant bits `carry` are ever different, because then `carry << 1` would produce an overflow).

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.  OP is lucky the C version works at all.

Comment: Could you explain "then all of the digits except for the rightmost 31 digits get collapsed into a single bit, so it does the remaining carries all at once." in more detail? thank you!

Comment: @laike9m: It might be easier to think about it in the opposite direction: when you convert from `int` to a (2's complement) binary numeral, you have to sign extend: the most significant digit expands to an infinitely repeated digit.

Comment: In order to get similar behaviour as the C++ version, you could supply numpy integers, which have a finite binary representation: aplusb(numpy.int32(100), numpy.int32(-100)) gives 0 as expected.

Answer (score 10):

The problem are negative numbers, or, how they are represented. In Python integer numbers have arbitrary accuracy, while C++ ints are 32bit or 64bit. So in Python, you have to handle negative numbers, e.g. subtraction, separately, or limit the number of bits by hand.

Comment: Can C++ have 8-bit, or 16-bit integers?  Last time I recall, there were more than two sizes for integers [in C++ numeric types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: I wonder if `-x` counts as one of the banned arithmetic operators here; just flipping the sign like that to change it into a subtraction problem is probably cheating.

Comment: @Smac89 As you can see from both links, there are more sizes for integers than 32 or 64 bit.  For example, the C++ language defines the minimum ranges that unsigned char, unsigned short int, unsigned int and unsigned long must support.  There is no maximum size specified.  A platform can use 128-bits to represent all those types.

Answer (score 8):

Following the great explanation by @Hurkyl , I stepped through the algorithm for `a=4` and `b=-4` using the fact that python implements an infinite two's compliment representation:

```
Step 0:

a = ...(0)...000100
b = ...(1)...111100

carry = a & b = ...(0)...000100
a = a ^ b = ...(1)...111000
b = carry << 1 = ...(0)...001000

Step 1:

a = ...(1)...111000
b = ...(0)...001000

carry = a & b = ...(0)...001000
a = a ^ b = ...(1)...110000
b = carry << 1 = ...(0)...010000

Step 2:

a = ...(1)...110000
b = ...(0)...010000

carry = a & b = ...(0)...010000
a = a ^ b = ...(1)...100000
b = carry << 1 = ...(0)...100000
```

It is clear that there needs to be an effective cutoff to emulate something like a 32-bit signed two's compliment integer. Once the carry bit bubbles up beyond highest bit the algorithm needs to be halted. The following appears to work:

```
MAX_BIT = 2**32
MAX_BIT_COMPLIMENT = -2**32

def aplusb(a, b):

    while b != 0:
        if b == MAX_BIT:
            return a ^ MAX_BIT_COMPLIMENT
        carry = a & b
        a = a ^ b
        b = carry << 1

    return a
```

Results:

```
>>> aplusb(100,-100)
0
>>> aplusb(100,-99)
1
>>> aplusb(97,-99)
-2
>>> aplusb(1000,-500)
500
>>> aplusb(-1000,8000)
7000
```

Comment: If you take this approach, then rather than hardcoding an upper bound, you might consider determining the cutoff dynamically; e.g. so that your program would be able to give the correct results when adding two 87-bit numbers, or so that it could stop early if adding two 4-bit numbers. e.g. see [bit_length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length). I think, as you've currently written it, your implementation would get stuck in a loop again if the numbers are bigger than 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

If 1-bit binary math operations (^) are forbidden, go for unary!

```
from itertools import chain

def unary(x):
    "Unary representation of x"
    return ''.join(['x' for _ in range(0,x)])

def uplus(x, y):
    "Unary sum of x and y"
    return [c for c in chain(x,y)]

def plus(i, j):
    "Return sum calculated using unary math"
    return len(uplus(unary(i), unary(j)))
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because python is not normally using 32 bit signed int.

See:[ctypes.c_int32](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int32)

Accepted solution:

```
class Solution:
"""
@param a: The first integer
@param b: The second integer
@return:  The sum of a and b
"""
def aplusb(self, a, b):
    import ctypes
    a = ctypes.c_int32(a).value
    a = ctypes.c_int32(a).value
    while b != 0:
        carry = ctypes.c_int32(a & b).value
        a = ctypes.c_int32(a ^ b).value
        b = ctypes.c_int32(carry << 1).value

    return a
```

Comment: Or we can import c_int32 only like this: `from ctypes import c_int32` and use like this: `a = c_int32(a).value`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def foo(a, b):
"""iterate through a and b, count iteration via a list, check len"""
    x = []
    for i in range(a):
            x.append(a)
    for i in range(b):
            x.append(b)
    print len(x)
```

As already stated, bitwise is better.