# Calculator Program in Ruby/Python without using any built in operators

Tags: python, ruby, oop

I was recently asked this in an interview for junior dev position. I was asked to create a calculator program that can add,subtract, multiply and divide without using the built in +,-,*,/ operators. Essentially to build it from the ground up.

I had no idea how to solve this. Does anyone have any guidance on how to implement at least one of the operations? I can figure out the rest from there but really need some guidance.

I code in both python and ruby.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696484/a-b-without-arithmetic-operators-python-vs-c

Comment: Your question is very broad. We don't know your expertise, since "I code in both python and ruby." really tells us little.

Comment: Hint: If you ignore *most* of the methods and squint at the rest just right, it becomes immediately obvious that Ruby's implementation of `Integer`s is basically just an object-oriented interpretation of the Church encoding (which you know from basic CS) of Peano numbers (which you know from basic maths) in the lambda-calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study how Ruby's "operators" are implemented; They're methods and [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) can be used as an alternate way of calling them.

From the documentation:

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified....

```
class Klass
  def hello(*args)
    "Hello " + args.join(' ')
  end
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers"   #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

From that:

```
1.send(:+, 1) # => 2
```

Learning more about that is left as an exercise for the reader.

If you really want to dive in, you could create base methods like:

```
class Fixnum
  def add(value)
    val = self
    value.times do
      val = val.succ
    end
    val
  end
end

1.add(1) # => 2
```

Comment: I don't think the point of the exercise was to simply call the illegal operators using send. He probably wants to look at how mathematical operations are performed at a lower level i.e. binary.

Comment: We don't know what the OP wants as it's not defined, and that's why the question is too broad. I'm presenting basics of how to do it in Ruby, which is what I'd have meant if I'd asked that sort of question in an interview.

Comment: thanks, this helped alot!

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of addition.

```
class Integer
  def add(int) # int is 5 in the demo
    res = self # 7 in the demo
    int.times{res = res.succ} # succ just adds 1
    return res
  end
end

# demo
p 7.add(5) # => 12
```

Apart from `succ`, the Integer class has a `pred` method, which subtracts 1. Really useful for building a `subtract` method. Multiplying is just adding multiple times, and integer division is just subtracting multiple times.

Comment: This. If you ignore the operators and focus *just* on those three methods, it becomes immediately obvious that Ruby's implementation of `Integer`s is basically just an object-oriented interpretation of the Church encoding of Peano numbers in the lambda-calculus.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Hear, hear.