# Time exceeded when use python to solve lintcode a+b problem

Tags: python

[Write a function that add two numbers A and B.](https://www.lintcode.com/problem/a-b-problem/description)

```py
 class Solution:
    """
    @param a: An integer
    @param b: An integer
    @return: The sum of a and b 
    """
    def aplusb(self, a, b):
        # write your code here

        while True:
            a, b = a^b, (a&b)<<1
            if a==0 or b == 0:
                return a or b
```

Hint
Your code ran too much time than we expected. Check your time complexity. Time limit exceeded usually caused by infinite loop if your time complexity is the best.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30696484/7351855

Comment: Possible duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557464/sum-of-two-integers-without-using-operator-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557464/sum-of-two-integers-without-using-operator-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of Two Integers without using "+" operator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557464/sum-of-two-integers-without-using-operator-in-python)